# XSL select first line plain text

Tags: xslt, linefeed

I have an xml file with content type plain text.What i want to do is use the first line as a headline in an xsl transformation.How should it be formed?I ve tried with various terms as a delimeter ,like
 but no result.
the input

```
<contentSet>
<inlineData contenttype="text/plain" >
Et, sent luptat luptat, commy nim zzriureet vendreetue modo
dolenis ex euisis nosto et lan ullandit lum doloreet vulla
feugiam coreet, cons eleniam il ute facin veril et aliquis ad
minis et lor sum del iriure dit la feugiamcommy nostrud min ulla
</inlineData>
</contentSet>
```

and want to have output something like this

```
<doc>
<story>
<headline>
  Et, sent luptat luptat, commy nim zzriureet vendreetue modo   
 </headline>
<text>
Et, sent luptat luptat, commy nim zzriureet vendreetue modo
dolenis ex euisis nosto et lan ullandit lum doloreet vulla
feugiam coreet, cons eleniam il ute facin veril et aliquis ad
minis et lor sum del iriure dit la feugiamcommy nostrud min ulla
</text>
</story>
</doc>
```

Comment: can you gibe a sample of your input and the desired output?

Comment: not your question, but might also work: use the first X characters. E.g. substring(inlineData,1,100)

Answer (score 5):

Well technically the first line in your `inlineData` element is empty and only the second line contains text. Assuming that structure is the same for all input you want to process you can use

```
<xsl:template match="contentSet">
  <story>
    <headline><xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after(inlineData, '&#10;'), '&#10;')"/></headline>
    <text><xsl:value-of select="."/></text>
  </story>
</xsl:template>
```

I realize that is brittle but string processing in XSLT/XPath 1.0 is weak, in XSLT 2.0 you could use `<xsl:value-of select="tokenize(inlineData, '\n')[normalize-space()][1]"/>`.